# NLog in ASP.NET - what permissions should the log file have (archiving issue)

Tags: asp.net, logging, permissions, nlog

For an ASP.Net environment what permissions should the logging file created by NLog have ? The ASP.Net virtual directory is using an application pool which has an 'Application Pool Identity' of 'Network Service'.

When I grant 'Network Service' change rights to the NLog output file all is well until the archiving condition causes the initial log file to become X_0001 and a new X to be created - the new X now longer has any rights for 'Network Service' and so an error is generated when the ASP.Net scripts try to write to it.

I can't find any reference to this on the NLog site. Any info welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign permissions to a folder and make sure permissions get inherited by the files created in this folder. This way any new file create will automatically get permissions you need.